# Standard Normal Distribution Question: Help?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

**Q: entry to a job requires taking a test. The mean score is 500, the standard deviation is 100, and the scores are normally distributed. To get the interview, you need to score in the top 10% of the score distribution. How much does he have to score to be admitted?**

So, I have a standard normal dist. table. I thought about transforming this problem to the standard normal dist. So:

Z score = X - mean / standard deviation

The mean is 500, and standard deviation is 100.

So, basically, the value for X is unknown, but we know they need to score in the top 10%. Therefore, I found 0.9 (bottom 90%) on the standard normal table (since the lowest value is 0.5), which has a Z score of 1.28. Therefore, X - 500 / 100 = 1.28. Solving this for X, we get 628. Does this mean 628 is the score they need to achieve on the test, or have I done this completely wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  As for typesetting and asking questions on this site, I applaud your including your thoughts and attempts.  Thank you for that.  The post can still be cleaned up a great deal by utilizing [MathJax and $\LaTeX$ formatting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  As you have written it `X - 500 / 100` could (*and should normally without context*) be interpreted as $x-\frac{500}{100}$ instead of as $\frac{x-500}{100}$ as you intended.  At the *minimum* you should be using parentheses to make things clearer.

Comment: Apart from the question of whether they need more than $628$ or whether $628$ is enough (complicated by a small rounding issue), this looks reasonable

Comment: Exploring @Henry's small rounding issue: In R statistical software, `qnorm(.90, 500, 100)` [normal quantile or inverse CDF function] returns `628.1552`,  `pnorm(628, 500, 100)` [normal CDF function] returns `0.8997274` and `pnorm(628.5, 500, 100)` `0.9006039`. If a score of 628 means 'between 627.5 and 628.5', then a generous interpretation is that 628 is _barely_ enough.